# How to calculate the stock using FIFO method(MySQL8)

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask how to use the FIFO method with MYSQL8 to generate the expected result as follow.
The date of the stock in the result table must be the stock in date. Thanks to everyone if you can help.

Orginal_Table

| Stock Name | In/out | Quantity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | in | 10 | 1/1/2021 |
| Banana | in | 5 | 1/2/2021 |
| Banana | out | 3 | 1/5/2021 |
| Banana | in | 4 | 1/6/2021 |
| Cherry | in | 3 | 1/6/2021 |
| Cherry | in | 4 | 1/7/2021 |
| Cherry | out | 5 | 1/8/2021 |

Expected_result

| Stock Name | balance | stock_in_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | 1/1/2021 |
| Banana | 2 | 1/2/2021 |
| Banana | 4 | 1/6/2021 |
| Cherry | 2 | 1/7/2021 |

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT name, SUM(quantity * (operation = 'out')) went_out
    FROM test
    GROUP BY name
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(quantity * (operation = 'in')) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY operation_date) amount
    FROM test
)
SELECT name, 
       operation_date,
       CASE WHEN amount - quantity < went_out 
            THEN amount - went_out
            ELSE quantity
            END result
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 USING (name)
WHERE operation = 'in'
  AND went_out < amount
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ad523920d50fddfb38e609c5e1f9147) with query building steps.

Comment: Thanks dude. That is really what I want. Much appreciate.